# Is there a formal definition of the $\because$ (because) symbol? If so, what is it?

Tags: logic, definition

Is there a formal definition of the $\because$ (because) symbol?  If so, what is it?

I use (or abuse?) the $\because$ symbol to introduce assumptions, definitions, or to other assertions.  I first encountered it in a formal logic course in which the professor openly bragged about not using it in a strictly correct way.

I am adding a screen scrape of what I was working on when I asked the question.  These are personal notes with a target audience consisting of the author.  I decided to attempt an explanation that I might give to another reader if such a mythical creature were to exist.  The particular statement captures a number of my notational idiosyncratices, so it seemed like a good subject.

[image]

Comment: compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921396/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231664/42969

Comment: My advice: in material to be read by others, do not use $\because$, but instead write words (like "since").

Comment: Neither of the referenced questions have satisfying answers.  Perhaps $\because$ (because) means 'because' is the best I can hope for.

Comment: @GEdgar using word kind of defeats the whole "symbolic" part of symbolic logic.  The $\because$ symbol may not be logically necessary, but it is convenient.

Comment: @mauro you closed this as a duplucate, but this question is about the "because" symbol and  the other question does not have any answers that mention that. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @steven I have never actually seen this used, and I wonder if it fell out of general use even before the beginning of mathematical logic in the late 19th century. In which case there would not be any formal definition, beyond "it is an abbreviation of 'because'". The use in your example is not standard.

Comment: No "because" symbol in logic.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231664/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-math-symbol-because)?

Comment: @Steven: These symbols are only convenient for the few people who use them. For most people who read mathematics as humans, this symbol is just another thing you need to look up online or try and figure out from the context.

Comment: IMO, what you are writing is simply: "if $[ A \land B \to C]$, then $D \land E$" that can also be written as $[ A \land B \to C] \therefore D \land E$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $[ A \land B \to C] \therefore D \land E$ is a good idea.  I will take it under advisement.